# Need resources to learn about Graph Spanners

Tags: graphs, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to learn about Graph Spanners. I have searched for it but unfortunately, I couldn't find any solid helpful resource related to this very topic.

I would highly appreciate if anyone can suggest me any specific book or online material which explains about Graph Spanners in detail.

Comment: Graph spanners is a pretty large and (I believe) too diverse topic for single authoritative books on the topic. Can you narrow your search to particular kinds of spanners?

Comment: I'm just starting with graph spanners and I have no idea what they are. So, basically I'm looking for some resources to get started. Please suggest anything which you think will be suitable as a starting point for someone who has decent knowledge of Graph Theory.

Comment: 'Just starting': In what context? Surely you have some sort of goal or reason to learn about spanners other than 'I want to learn about them'? If so, please tell us! If not, I suggest re-evaluating why you wish to learn about spanners.

Comment: Okay, so the scene is I'm an undergraduate student and I want to get some experience with research work. So, I decided to work on Graph Theory. Now to get the research internship I have to prepare myself. And this is the reason why I want to learn about spanners...